# Change the MobileStepper color on React Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I implemented a [progress stepper](https://material-ui.com/demos/steppers/) from Material UI and I can't find a way to change its background color from purple to blue.

Following the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/mobile-stepper/#css-api) I've tried to change it by setting the `progress` property on `styles` but it applies a new background color instead of changing the color of the progress bar...

```
const styles = {
  progress: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  }
};
<MobileStepper
    variant="progress"
    steps={3}
    position="static"
    activeStep={this.state.activeStep}
    className={classes.progress}
    nextButton={
        <Button size="small" onClick={this.handleNext} disabled={this.state.activeStep === 2}>
            Next
            {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <KeyboardArrowLeft /> : <KeyboardArrowRight />}
        </Button>
    }
    backButton={
            <Button size="small" onClick={this.handleBack} disabled={this.state.activeStep === 0}>
            {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <KeyboardArrowRight /> : <KeyboardArrowLeft />}
            Back
        </Button>
    }
/>
```

This is how it looks right now:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the color property instead of backgroundColor?

```
const styles = {
  progress: {
    color: 'blue',
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const MobileStepperView = withStyles({
  root: {
    width: "50%",
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  colorPrimary: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
  progress: {
    backgroundColor: "green",
    "& *": {
      backgroundColor: "red",
    },
  },
})(MobileStepper);
```

Try this, hope it will help.